# What syntax can I use for quoted identifiers in Flink Table SQL?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-calcite

I'm trying to use quoted identifiers in Flink (mainly because I have some column names that conflict with keywords like `year`). But I can't make it parse.

I boiled down to a minimal failing example:

```
EnvironmentSettings settings = 
EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().useBlinkPlanner().inBatchMode().build();
TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);
 String sql = "CREATE TABLE table1(\"ts\" TIMESTAMP) WITH ('connector' = 'filesystem', 'path' = 'file:///Users/ecerulm/tmp/csv/', 'format' = 'csv');";
System.out.println(sql);
tEnv.executeSql(sql);
```

which fails complaining about the `"ts"` part:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.SqlParserException: SQL parse failed. Encountered "\"" at line 1, column 21.
Was expecting one of:
    "CONSTRAINT" ...
    "PRIMARY" ...
    "UNIQUE" ...
    "WATERMARK" ...
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <HYPHENATED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    

    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.calcite.CalciteParser.parse(CalciteParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.ParserImpl.parse(ParserImpl.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:658)
    at com.rubenlaguna.BatchJobTest.testBatchJob(BatchJobTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

As I understand from the exception it's not expecting the `"` character because it does not match any of the parsing alternatives like `<QUOTED_IDENTIFIER>` but as I understand from [Calcite documentation](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#identifiers) the syntax for quoted identifiers is just `"myidentifier"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Flink documentation for Expanding Table Identifiers](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/common.html#expanding-table-identifiers) says:

> Identifiers follow SQL requirements which means that they can be escaped with a backtick character (`).

It does **not mention double quoted identifiers**.

So although [Flink SQL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/sql/index.html) is based on Calcite SQL and although [Calcite has double quoted identifiers](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#identifiers) it seems that [Flink SQL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/sql/index.html) only supports the regular sql identifier + backquoted identifiers. So you will need to write the query like this:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE table1(`ts` TIMESTAMP) WITH ('connector' = 'filesystem', 'path' = 'file:///Users/ecerulm/tmp/csv/', 'format' = 'csv')";
tEnv.executeSql(sql);
```

so instead of `"ts"` (with double quotes) use `` `ts` `` (with backticks).